# Problems in finding the marginal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, density-function

I have some problems with this exercise:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real-valued random variables with a common density:

$f_{X,Y}=\left\{\begin{matrix} 2e^{-x-y} & 0<y<x \\ 0 & else \end{matrix}\right.$

a) Do the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ each have a density? If so, calculate them.

b) Are $X$ and $Y$ uncorrelated?

So for a) Why shouldnt exist a marginal distributions?

I have calculated them:
$f_x(x)=\int_0^x 2e^{-x-y}dy=2\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}-\mathrm{e}^{-2x}\right)$

and for $f_y(y)=2\mathrm{e}^{-y}$

Have I done everything right?

To see if there are correlated I have to check:

$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] \\ 
\int_0^x \int_0^{\infty}xy2e^{-x-y}dxdy=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2x\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}-\mathrm{e}^{-2x}\right)dx)(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2y\mathrm{e}^{-y}dy)$

The problem here that $E[X]$ diverges which makes me think that I have done something wrong. Can someone help me to make me understand where my error is?

Comment: [Hint](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+2e%5E%7B-x-y%7D+for+x%3Dy..infinity).

Comment: Thank you very much @KurtG. and the limits for calculating $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ should be $0$ and $\infty$, right?

Comment: Please try wolfram alpha to figure this out. Amend the question and we reconvene. Having said that: the marginals are densities on $[0,\infty)\,.$ Then the limits are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal densities are
$$
f_X(x)=\int_0^x 2\,e^{-x-y}\,dy=2\,(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})\,,\quad f_Y(y)=\int_y^\infty 2\,e^{-x-y}\,dx = 2\,e^{-2y}\,.
$$
which are both defined on $[0,\infty)\,.$

Your last formula looks totally wrong. It should be
$$
\mathbb E[XY]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^x 2\,x\,y\,e^{-x-y}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^\infty 2\,x\,e^{-x}\underbrace{\int_0^xy\,e^{-y}\,dy}_{(*)}\,dx\,.
$$
From
$$
(*)=\int_0^xy\,e^{-y}\,dy=\int_0^xe^{-y}\,dy-y\,e^{-y}\Big|_0^x=1-e^{-x}-x\,e^{-x}
$$
we get
$$
\mathbb E[XY]=\int_0^\infty 2\,x\,e^{-x}(1-e^{-x}-x\,e^{-x})\,dx=1\,.
$$
The random variables are not uncorrelated because
$$
\mathbb E[X]=\int_0^\infty 2\,x\,(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})\,dx=\frac{3}{2}\,,\quad \mathbb E[Y]=\int_0^\infty 2\,y\,e^{-2y}\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\,.
$$